# Issue with Updating Model in Razor View

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

first post. Trying so solve an issue I am seeing here between my Razor view and model. I have a popup window that is being fed a partial view and model.

```
 public IActionResult ClickedCovid19Question(int id)
    {
        var existingQ = db.CustomerInfoItems.Find(id);

        var suffix = existingQ.Suffix;

        if (suffix.Length == 2)
            suffix = suffix.Insert(0, "0");

        var salesman = SalesmanHelper.GetSalesmanNum();

        var par = db.Pars.Where(p => p.AccountNo == existingQ.CustNum).Where(p => p.Suffix == suffix)
                    .Where(p => p.SalesmanNumber == salesman).FirstOrDefault();
        var clickedCovid19Model = new ClickedCovidQuestionModel
        { //insert model data here }
        
        clickedCovid19Model.Machines = db.MachinePopulationItems
            .Where(m => m.CustNum == existingQ.CustNum)
            .ToList();

        return View("~/Views/Covid19/_ClickedCovid19Question.cshtml", clickedCovid19Model);
    }
```

This works great on the first page render. I see the data fill my UI elements that are called from the @model on the razor page. When my user updates a field here and submits, I use this function

```
function SaveClickedCovid19Question(idJS) {
    C19ParChanged('@Model.Par');
    var jsonJS = SerializeForm("#c19QuestionForm");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Covid19/SaveClickedCovid19Question',
        type: 'GET',
        data:
        {
            id: idJS,
            json: jsonJS
        },
        success: function (data) {
            Alert(data);
            RefreshLV("CovidQuestions");
            HideWindow("#Covid19Question");
        },
        error: function (data, error, e2) {
            debugger;
        }
    });
}
```

However, after the popup window is closed, and another popup is opened, we call that same ClickedCovid19Question IActionResult to populate our form again. It populates the UI fine with the new model it generated, debugging shows it creates a new model with all the correct data.
The issue arrises when a user submits this form again, the model on the Razor view seems to think it is still the model of the very first submission. An example of this is the first line of the javascript function. When the razor view was created, it had the correct @Model.Par data, as I could see when I created a few elements to display it. However, when trying to capture that data using @Model.Par, it captures the original Model.Par data.
Long story short, subsequent popups don't overwrite the Model data from the very first one. I am stumped, because this system works in so many other areas of our codebase.
I can fix this buy creating hidden elements that will store the data I need to send in any requests, but I feel like there has to be a better answer than that.

Edit: Below is an example I was using to test. The view part below will always display the correct par data in the id=parID input box. However, on the second popup and everytime after, if I was to run the simple javascript function below to find the data held by model, it will ALWAYS update to the data from the first model the page ever rendered, which seems inconsistent with other areas of my code that do work normally.

```
function updateParID() {
        $("#c19QuestionForm").find("#parID").val('@Model.Par');

    }


<input id="parID" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="@Model.Par"/>
        <partial name="Forms/_FormDropDown" model=@(new FormDropDownModel { Name = "Par", Values = Lists.ParStates(), Value = Model.CallsPerYear}) />
        <button type="submit" onclick="RefreshWindow('@Model.ID')">Refresh</button>
        <button type="submit" onclick="updateParID()">Update Par ID</button>
```

Comment: Where is the part where you reload the view to get a refreshed model? @Model.Par came from the server the first time that javascript was served. Unless the page refreshed somewhere, it didn't get any updates. RefreshLV?

Comment: Can you add the `RefreshLV` function code?

Comment: I can still add it if you wish, but that code actually refreshes the ListView parent item that this popup window comes from. I have a ListView of many objects, that onclick give me the popup window that this code here is. That RefreshLV just updates that parent ListView in the event any other data going to our database changes. I could be wrong but my assumption is they aren't related to this issue

Comment: Hi @wlfreeman93, could you please share your view? Be sure the `idJS` in `SaveClickedCovid19Question(idJS)` is correct. If possible, please share more detailed js code.

Comment: Hi @Rena, I added an edit that shows a part of the view that I think summarizes my problem up well. If you need more I can add, the entire view is just quite large as it is a fairly large form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I actually ended up solving this. My issue was, trying to bind the data from the @Model.Par or any model data INSIDE a javascript function will ALWAYS bind using the initial model. Every subsequent call to this function will ALWAYS only use that very first model.
My solution that I overlooked was to actually send the data to the function from the model as a parameter first, and not try to bind it inside the javascript function.

Example: My edit has these lines

```
function updateParID() {
        $("#c19QuestionForm").find("#parID").val('@Model.Par');

    }

<button type="submit" onclick="updateParID()">Update Par ID</button>
```

When I change the order of how I capture that model to this:

```
function updateParID(parID) {
        $("#c19QuestionForm").find("#parID").val(parID);

    }

<button type="submit" onclick="updateParID('@Model.Par')">Update Par ID</button>
```

This now correctly captures the model data that is present. I am sure there is some reason javascript works this way, but it is unknown to me, if anyone can shed light on it. Forgive me if it is a simple answer, I am new to web programming. Thank you all for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

That @Model.Par (or whatever prop you have in @Model) renders before anything shows up in browser.
Razor page will render your view and then pass it to browser.
so if you want to fetch data using ajax you should manually put data received from ajax into you html controls.

Have a nice coding day :)

Comment: I probably didn't explain it thoroughly, my apologies, but all my ajax actually pulls back is a "Success" message, that goes to our over-ridden custom Alert there. On Success it just alerts user if it hit the database or not, refreshes the parent ListView in the case the data was changed, and hides the pop-up window that is having my issue.
While I know what you are saying would work, I just have another area with code nearly identical that works fine, the model is reset on each partial view render to the new model, and I can work with the data, this pop up page does not,